# Новая активность в 1 вопросе

Tags: лексическая-сочетаемость

Приглашение ***"Новая активность в 1 вопросе"*** — насколько оно звучит по-русски? Нет ли формулировки более подходящей? Активность, если кратко, — деятельное поведение. Заметить и назвать её характер и источник обычно нетрудно. Активность бывает солнечная, мышечная, творческая... Но новая?

Обновляют экран клавишей F5, но если стандартное (Обновление экрана) кажется неконкретным, то можно тремя словами сказать: Есть новый вопрос.

Comment: Формулировка вопроса: Насколько грамотной является фраза "новая активность в 1 вопросе?" Нет ли формулировки более подходящей?

Answer (score 1):

**Новая активность в  1 вопросе** – лучше и не скажешь, образцовый вариант, для термина вполне подходящий.

Другие сочетания, которые можно встретить в Сети: **недавняя активность, последняя активность** – мне нравятся гораздо меньше.

Comment: Недавняя — давнишняя, последняя — первая. Эти слова — другого ряда слова. Есть единственный пример, который не относится к IT-сленговым: http://www.csiconsulting.ru/links/itog_part_1.pdf, где 80 раз повторяется название проекта «Возрождение и новая активность - социальные новации» и ни разу не встречается «новой активности» в тексте. Калька — она и есть калька.

Comment: Насчёт ответа... Вспомнилась дискуссия, начинавшаяся бодрой фразой: «Я считаю, что это неполноценный ответ без объяснения».

Comment: Проведена определенная работа, сделаны выводы. Новая активность - сетевой термин (именное в этом плане его и надо рассматривать), у него есть аналоги (пришлось поискать). "Недавняя и последняя"  по семантике кажутся не очень подходящими, а вот "новая активность" - в самый раз. Можно рекомендовать другим форумам. Что же еще хотите?

Comment: Вы не хотели ответа без объяснений (даже требовались доказательства), Ваши «в самый раз, лучше и не скажешь, образцовый вариант» как квалифицировать? Песней примитивной кальке, думаю. Считаю, что такие термины пусть будут, но выпускать их в большую жизнь нельзя, особенно через  сайт неравнодушных русскоговорящих.=== Ещё раз: активность относится к  отвлечённым существительным, а они не допускают представления о количестве и счете качеств, свойств и процессов, которые они называют. В контексте о последнем заданном вопросе в ряду других «активность» подвергают трансформации. Вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Знаете, я могу согласиться, что первый ответ немного эмоциональный (сказано под влиянием  вопроса, сформулированного не лучшим образом). (А теперь я второй раз объясняю свою точку зрения.) Есть содержание такого характера: Уважаемые участники форума, обратите внимание на то, что в первом вопросе появились новые ответы, комментарии, исправления и т.д. Как это выразить кратко? Предприняты новые действия со стороны участников?  Всё не то, а вот активность - хорошее слово.

Comment: Из словаря: АКТИВНОСТЬ,  Деятельное участие в чём-л.  Познавательная, творческая а. А. общественных организаций. Проявлять а. Где  написано, что активность относится к отвлеченным существительным? (Например: Для таких детей  характерна низкая познавательная активность). Почему запрещено сочетание "новая активность", кто его запретил? Это ТЕРМИН, а для термина главное - КРАТКОСТЬ И ЯСНОСТЬ содержания. Таким образом, есть  понятие и требуется слово/словосочетание для его обозначения. У Вас есть другие  (лучшие) варианты?

Comment: О содержании обращения «в первом вопросе» — это фантазия не на тему, начиная с «уважаемых участников форума». Согласен с выводом, что активность — хорошее слово. Много других хороших абстрактных слов, но мы не встречаем посягательства на них, и тихо радуемся, что нет нового энтузиазма и старой пассивности, нового оптимизма и старого пессимизма, хотя ощущаем новый приход нового завтра, когда всё накроется новым тазом. Мои варианты: Активность в новом вопросе; Новый вопрос; Есть новый вопрос. «Новый вопрос» ещё никто не запрещал.

Comment: А новая радость, старая любовь - можно так говорить?  "Новый вопрос" - не подходит, а то потребуются другие конкретные названия: новый комментарий и т.д. " Активность в новом вопросе" - тоже не подойдет, если  вопрос уже утратил новизну.

Comment: Говорите, не отказывайте себе. Новая радость в 1 вопросе как иллюстрация — то, что надо.